# Trouble Deserializing with GZip

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, gzip

When i deserialize without GZip, it's done. But in deserializing with GZip i have deserialization error.

Serializing:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var compressionStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        serializator.Serialize(compressionStream, obj);
    }
    byte[] result = ms.ToArray();
    return result;
}
```

Deserializing:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(_objBytes))
{
    using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        return serializator.Deserialize(decompressionStream, null, objType, _objBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the number of bytes is wrong, I guess. You're passing the number of *compressed*  bytes to the deserializer when you should be passing the number of *uncompressed* bytes.

Comment: Which serializer do you use?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar : how can i pass uncompressed bytes?

Comment: @AlekseyL. : protobuf. But i don't this what the problem in serializer

Comment: I'd try to just decompress the stream into an array of bytes and then use that again as source of another memory stream you deserialize from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments the number of bytes is wrong. Why are you ever specifying it? You can use overload without length parameter:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Deserialize(decompressionStream, null, objType);
```

Comment: Thank you. It work: return serializator.Deserialize(gzipStream, null, objType);